# Save email attachment if containing keywordin filename

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to extract a pdf file from Outlook if that pdf contains "ecritures" in the filename.

So far my code is running just fine extracting the pdf from a subfolder but I would like to add this if condition:

Extracting pdf files:

```
For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
   For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
      If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "pdf" Then
         FileName = "file path"
         Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
         i = i + 1
      End If
   Next Atmt
Next Item
```

I've been reading other post suggesting to use the InStr(UCase but it hasn't been working for me. It seems I'm doing it wrong since it doesn't return a value for the keyword "ecritures". Anyone has a clue? Below my code:

```
For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
   For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
      If InStr(UCase(Atmt.FileName), "ecritures") > 0 Then
         FileName = "file path"
         Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
         i = i + 1
      End If
   Next Atmt
Next Item
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using `UCase` you should compare to `ECRITURES`. Or use `If InStr(LCase(Atmt.FileName), "ecritures") > 0 Then`...

Comment: Great, thank you Robin!

Comment: Pas de soucis...

Comment: For those who repeatedly trip on this apply UCase or LCase on both parts. If InStr(UCase(Atmt.FileName), UCase("ecritures")) > 0 Then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to ensure they were ***also*** PDFs, then you could utilise the `Like` operator:

```
If LCase(Atmt.FileName) like "*ecritures*.pdf" Then
```

The above would require that the filename ***contained*** `ecritures` but also that the file suffix (in lower case) was `.pdf`.

Using `"ecritures*.pdf"` (removing the first asterisk) would be similar, but would require that the filename ***starts*** with `ecritures` instead of just contain it.